# Python BaseHTTPServer stream JSON data - high CPU

Tags: python, http, stream

I would like to stream json data over http. Ultimately, the data will come from the device `/dev/USB` for now I create variable and I mock simple json string. I'm create get endpoin using `BaseHTTPServer`. When I try to recive  stream using crul I gets data but during reciving data server process uses **100%** of CPU. Why and how to correct this? Maby my idea is wrong?

```
from BaseHTTPServer import BaseHTTPRequestHandler, HTTPServer
import socket as Socket


class StreamServer(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

    def do_GET(self):
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/stream+json")
        self.send_header('Connection', 'keep-alive')
        self.end_headers()

        while True:
            //mock variable, in the future data will come from device
            string = "{ test: 12 }"
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(string)

def main():
    try:

        StreamServer.ip = "0.0.0.0"
        StreamServer.hostname = Socket.gethostname()
        server = HTTPServer((StreamServer.ip, 7777), StreamServer)
        print("server started on {}".format(Socket.gethostname()))
        server.serve_forever()

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('KeyboardInterrupt')

    server.socket.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

EDIT:

I add sleep(0.1666) function end of the while loop and CPU decreased to 75%

Comment: It looks like you have an infinite loop in your do_GET method. Your 'while True' loop never finishes, does it?

Comment: Yes, because I would like to read infinite data from device. I correct CPU usage adding sleep function end of the while loop

Comment: I don't get it. There is no sleep call in the code you posted so high CPU usage is normal, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, there is no sleep call in the question. I make some experiment now.

Comment: And if you increase the sleep time (e.g. to 0.5) you will consume even less CPU usage. Unrelated to CPU usage, as far as I know there is no way to send _infinite_ content over HTTP. You _can_ use chunked transfer encoding (to transfer an arbitrary sized response of finite size) but even in this case you have to end the transfer at some point.